# How to get standard indents padding flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I introduce standard padding for Flutter container?
Does Flutter supply any constants or should i use custom widget?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap it in a padding widget. Check the different options on EdgeInsets to pad only what you need or everything.

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(),
    )
```

If you have a Column and want everything inside to have the same horizontal padding then better just to do it there instead of adding redundant padding to each of the children.

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(),
        ],
      ),
    )
```